# Assigning hyperlinks to nodes in dagre-d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, dagre-d3

I am using this graph http://cpettitt.github.io/project/dagre-d3/latest/demo/tcp-state-diagram.html. I need when clicked on nodes it should be directed to some web address.

I tried this:

```
<    html xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <style>
        body {
            font: 300 14px 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica;
        }

        .node circle {
            stroke: #333;
            fill: #ff0000;
        }

        .edgePath path {
            stroke: #00ff90; /* Arrow color */
            fill: #ff0000; /* Arrow Tip color */
            stroke-width: 1.5px;
        }
        /* Make it obvious the node is clickable */
        .node.clickable {
            cursor: pointer;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <`svg width=960 height=600><g /></svg>`
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cpettitt.github.io/project/dagre-d3/v0.2.9/dagre-d3.js"></script>
    <script src="dagre-d3.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="lib/dagre-d3.core.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/graphlib.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/intersect/index.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/intersect/intersect-circle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/intersect/intersect-ellipse.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/intersect/intersect-line.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/intersect/intersect-node.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/intersect/intersect-polygon.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/intersect/intersect-rect.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/version.js"></script>-->
    <script>
        var g = new dagreD3.graphlib.Graph().setGraph({});

        // States and transitions from RFC 793
        var states = ["CLOSED", "LISTEN", "SYN RCVD", "SYN SENT",
        "ESTAB", "FINWAIT-1", "CLOSE WAIT", "FINWAIT-2",
        "CLOSING", "LAST-ACK", "TIME WAIT"];

        // Automatically label each of the nodes
        states.forEach(function (state) { g.setNode(state, { label: state, shape: "circle", href: 'https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre-d3' }); });

        // Set up the edges
        g.setEdge("CLOSED", "LISTEN", { label: "open" });
        g.setEdge("LISTEN", "SYN RCVD", { label: "rcv SYN" });
        g.setEdge("LISTEN", "SYN SENT", { label: "send" });
        g.setEdge("LISTEN", "CLOSED", { label: "close" });
        g.setEdge("SYN RCVD", "FINWAIT-1", { label: "close" });
        g.setEdge("SYN RCVD", "ESTAB", { label: "rcv ACK of SYN" });
        g.setEdge("SYN SENT", "SYN RCVD", { label: "rcv SYN" });
        g.setEdge("SYN SENT", "ESTAB", { label: "rcv SYN, ACK" });
        g.setEdge("SYN SENT", "CLOSED", { label: "close" });
        g.setEdge("ESTAB", "FINWAIT-1", { label: "close" });
        g.setEdge("ESTAB", "CLOSE WAIT", { label: "rcv FIN" });
        g.setEdge("FINWAIT-1", "FINWAIT-2", { label: "rcv ACK of FIN" });
        g.setEdge("FINWAIT-1", "CLOSING", { label: "rcv FIN" });
        g.setEdge("CLOSE WAIT", "LAST-ACK", { label: "close" });
        g.setEdge("FINWAIT-2", "TIME WAIT", { label: "rcv FIN" });
        g.setEdge("CLOSING", "TIME WAIT", { label: "rcv ACK of FIN" });
        g.setEdge("LAST-ACK", "CLOSED", { label: "rcv ACK of FIN" });
        g.setEdge("TIME WAIT", "CLOSED", { label: "timeout=2MSL" });

        // Set some general styles
        g.nodes().forEach(function (v) {
            var node = g.node(v);
            node.rx = node.ry = 4;
        });

        // Add some custom colors based on state
        g.node('CLOSED').style = "fill: #f77";
        g.node('ESTAB').style = "fill: #7f7";

        var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        inner = svg.select("g");

        // Set up zoom support
        var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
            inner.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" +
            "scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
        });
        svg.call(zoom);

        // Create the renderer
        var render = new dagreD3.render();

        // Run the renderer. This is what draws the final graph.
        render(inner, g);

        // Center the graph
        var initialScale = 0.75;
        zoom
        .translate([(svg.attr("width") - g.graph().width * initialScale) / 2, 20])
        .scale(initialScale)
        .event(svg);
        svg.attr('height', g.graph().height * initialScale + 40);
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried this concept : http://jsbin.com/siyorezedi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

but my nodes are not clickable and no error is thrown.

Can anyone please tell me where am I going wrong?
Thanking you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Try this. The first argument is the node id. The second is
metadata about the node.

`g.setNode("nodeN1", {
   labelType: "html",
   label: "<a href=https://www.google.com>Google</a>"
})`